# Can't Aggregate in Mongoose. Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'm trying to group data (WaterConsumption to be specific), by the date:
if creationDate = creationDate I want to sum the WaterConsumption.
But I'm kinda confused how Mongoose Aggregate works.
My Data:

```
    {
      "_id": "60538930f4bb883b0fe40f2f",
      "creationDate": "2021-02-03T17:12:04.022Z",
      "duration": 400,
      "voltage": "220",
      "avgPower": 6241,
      "maxPower": 6473,
      "WaterConsumption": 27,
      "avgTemperature": 36,
      "shower": "5fb56ce7734b7e04b9c97c9b",
      "user": "5f6cb0496a8c5a0deaa1a746",
      "__v": 0,
      "id": "60538930f4bb883b0fe40f2f"
    },
    {
      "_id": "60538bfc49a75c3ca75c0088",
      "creationDate": "2021-02-16T17:21:00.615Z",
      "duration": 900,
      "voltage": "220",
      "avgPower": 4300,
      "maxPower": 5600,
      "WaterConsumption": 32,
      "avgTemperature": 28,
      "shower": "5fb56d04734b7e04b9c97c9c",
      "user": "5f6cb0496a8c5a0deaa1a746",
      "__v": 0,
      "id": "60538bfc49a75c3ca75c0088"
    }...
```

My Code:

```
    let dateTwo = Measure.aggregate([
        {$match: {creationDate: "$creationDate"}},
        {$group: {_id: "$id", total: {$sum: "$WaterConsumption"}}}
    ])
```

I was able to do this using JavaScript but I can't figure out how can I do this using Mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using the code:

```
    let dateTwo = await Measure.aggregate([
        {$match: {duration: 360}},
        {$group: {_id: "$user", total: {$sum: "$WaterConsumption"}}}
    ]);
```